# Taking PNG from Desktop while jar is running

Tags: jar, io

I'm working on a project on an IDE, of course when using it I have no problems saving files into resources and using them. Though, I'm running the .jar of the project on a raspbian system and the image file is saved on Desktop, the same directory where the jar is saved, not a problem actually, the main problem is that I need to access that file and it does not let me, giving me a `FileNotFoundException`. Here is the code:

```
ImageIO.write(bi, "png", new File("mandelbrot.png"));
SendPhoto spr = new SendPhoto();
spr.setChatId(update.getMessage().getChatId());
spr.setReplyToMessageId(update.getMessage().getMessageId());
spr.setPhoto(new File("home/pi/Desktop/mandelbrot.png"));    //I've also tried with ~/Desktop/mandelbrot.png
```

The exact error is the following one:

```
Mar 07, 2019 6:24:58 PM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: I/O exception (java.io.FileNotFoundException) caught when processing request to {s}->https://api.telegram.org:443: home/pi/Desktop/mandelbrot.png (No such file or directory)
Mar 07, 2019 6:24:58 PM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: Retrying request to {s}->https://api.telegram.org:443
Mar 07, 2019 6:24:58 PM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: I/O exception (java.io.FileNotFoundException) caught when processing request to {s}->https://api.telegram.org:443: home/pi/Desktop/mandelbrot.png (No such file or directory)
Mar 07, 2019 6:24:58 PM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: Retrying request to {s}->https://api.telegram.org:443
Mar 07, 2019 6:24:58 PM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: I/O exception (java.io.FileNotFoundException) caught when processing request to {s}->https://api.telegram.org:443: home/pi/Desktop/mandelbrot.png (No such file or directory)
Mar 07, 2019 6:24:58 PM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: Retrying request to {s}->https://api.telegram.org:443
```

I have little knowledge on how a jar file works, so I assume I'm doing something wrong, because it makes no sense otherwise since that directory exists.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, it was a misunderstanding. I needed to write just `mandelbrot.png` and not all to path to get to the file, since it's in the same directory. I leave this in case someone will need it.